# Android on key down

Tags: android, onkeydown

I am working on a mini game for Android. When I click and hold down the button that I am clicking I expect that a event should be triggered once at a interval of time.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
        moveLeft();
        return (true);
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
        moveRight();
        return (true);
    }
}
```

This code works if I am using the simulator and the arrows in my keyboard. 
I also put down 2 Buttons on the layout and now want the same efect the object to move left or right when the button is touched at a interval of time. 
How can I do that ?

Comment: Could you elabourate as to what you mean by "at a interval of time"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What button? 
there's no left and right button on android phones.

but anyway the best way to do that kinda depends on how your game is built I guess, you probably should use either a postDelay or a thread.

maybe you can try setting a boolean that will be set to true when the key is down and false when its up and then run a postDelay when the key is down like so

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
          if (movingLeft) //your boolean
              moveLeft();
        }
    },1000); //time interval in milliseconds
```

don't forget to kill it, you don't want thousands of handlers running .. 
I don't really have any experience in programming games though..
hope it helps.